# Looking to export word template from Sharepoint RichText content field

Tags: sharepoint, report, rtf, rich-text-editor

I want to print sharepoint rich text field which has multiple tables and images on word document by using C#. I've tried SSRS but no luck yet and searched for different libraries but all are just render the text of rtf not the tables and images. Thank you.
#Note: Looking for free library